# Generating separate instances; passing list of instances as *args

Tags: python, function, class, instance, args

I have created 5 instances of a class and need to call another class with arguments from the instances like so:

```
class Class2:
    ...

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.time = 0
        ...

    def run_loop(self, arg, *args):
        ...

        while True:
            fn_with_args(*args)
            ...

            if self.time == 35:
                fn_print_exit()
                break

    def fn_with_args(self, *args):
        for i in args:
            if i != "none":
                fn_other()


clas1_ob1  = Clas1(arg1, arg2)
clas1_ob2  = Clas1(arg1, arg2)
clas1_ob3  = Clas1(arg1, arg2)
clas1_ob4  = Clas1(arg1, arg2)
clas1_ob5  = Clas1(arg1, arg2)

clas2_ob1  = Clas2(arg)

clas2_ob1.run_loop(clas1_ob1, "none")
clas2_ob1.run_loop(clas1_ob2, clas1_ob1)
clas2_ob1.run_loop(clas1_ob3, clas1_ob1, clas1_ob2)
clas2_ob1.run_loop(clas1_ob4, clas1_ob1, clas1_ob2, clas1_ob3)
clas2_ob1.run_loop(clas1_ob5, clas1_ob1, clas1_ob2, clas1_ob3, clas1_ob4)
```

Its obviously pretty ugly, but it does work at the moment. However, I would of course prefer to not have to write out each instance and then write out each call. I would prefer to run for loops in both cases.

I could of course, use lists, but when I tried it did not work because I could not iterate through lists of objects in the function fn_with_args(). *args however, can be iterated through. So my question presently is 'how can I pass *args into the run_loop() call so I can simply call it once?'

Or if there is a way I can iterate over the list of objects I suppose that is an option too however I would prefer to not do this because it requires many more lines of code and a fair bit of re-structuring.

Any and all input appreciated, let me know if I need explain more,

Thanks

PS: I realize also that I could simply pass the elements of the object into a list but this presents different problems for the program and seems counter to oop structure.

EDIT--->
Example:

```
number = 5
clas2_ob1  = Clas2(arg)
for i in range(number):
    clas1_ob1 = Clas1(arg1, arg2)
    clas2_ob1.run_loop(clas1_ob1, "none")
#This is the structure I want but this will obviously just overwrite 5 times
#The arguments in this case also become incorrect
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [the other use of star-args](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)?

Comment: Please show an example of what you want to do, and what you want the result to be.

Comment: I'll edit one in, but its difficult to do so because I don't know how; the best I can provide is an example that will not work.

Comment: user2357112, could you be a little more specific about the 'other use of star args'?

Comment: I looked closer, and you're already using both uses of star-args. Why not make a list of arguments and slice it for the number of arguments you want to use? `thing.do_thing(*args[:number_of_args])`

Comment: I think you may have been right, apparently *list enters the contents of a list as individual arguments. I was 'just looking for the other use of star-args'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to do what you want using a slice of a list of potential arguments:

```
class1_objs = [Clas1(arg1, arg2) for _ in range(5)]    # create Class1 objects in a list
class2_obj  = Clas2(arg)

for i, obj in enumerate(class1_objs):     # loop over objects and indexes with enumerate
    class2_obj.runloop(obj, *class1_objs[:i] or ["none"])  # use index to slice the list
```

I'd suggest however that you might want to redesign your method signatures to simply accept two arguments, an object and a sequence. The code you've shown packs and unpacks the arguments over and over, which is somewhat wasteful if you don't need it. Just get rid of the `*`s in all of the function definitions and their calls and you'll have simpler, more efficient code.

Comment: Just to clarify, you first created a list of class 1 instances. Then you iterated through them with enumerate, and called them as arguments in runloop() using the * operator with a 'or "none"' clause? Sorry, I just don't usually use list comprehensions.

Comment: I guess the magic here is how you were able to funnel all of those instances into the runloop() call without using a list.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I probably should have commented the code a bit more. The first line creates the same 5 `Class1` instances you were creating before, but puts them in a list rather than in separate variables. Then each pass of the `for` loop gives you one of the objects, and its index. The call to `runloop` then uses that index as the endpoint of a slice (with a list containing only `"none"` being substituted if the slice is empty). The `*whatever` syntax unpacks the list into the function call (though as I noted at the end, it just gets packed up again in a tuple within the function).

Comment: `enumerate` is used to get indices that are used to slice the `class1_objs`. A [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) is used in the `runloop` call, which works basically the same way as a list comprehension, and the generated values are unpacked with the `*`.

Comment: before I was getting an error when I tried to iterate through a list of objects. Is the solution just using a tuple with the * operator?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: There's no generator expression. The parentheses around the `or` expression are just regular parentheses. And in fact they don't seem to be necessary.... I don't think I've ever tested where the `*` unpacking operator falls in the operator precedence (or if it does at all), and it seems that `func(*lst1 or lst2)` works just fine.

Comment: ok the answer was just *list, to enter all of the list contents as individual arguments. Cool.